# Creat File Explorer for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-sdk

I am new to Windows Phone development. I want to create a file explorer app. Please suggest a path to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a file explorer in windows phone. The only files your app allowed access to are limited to files created by your app or shared to your app by another app through file association.

Comment: then will you tell me plz how music player is able to access all the file.

Comment: The music player is a built-in app.

Answer (score 0):

You just don't have the rights to access any content in the outer scope of your app, by exception of some windows apis you can call to use some of the functionality provided by them.